# Definitions of Reflexivity

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, operator-algebras

I have met reflexive with two definitions:

1. If $A$ is a normed space, then $A$ is reflexive whenever $A=A^{**}$.
2. An operator algebra $A$ is reflexive if the algebra can be recovered from
   its invariant subspace lattice $L = Lat(A)$ as the set $Alg(L)$ of all operators leaving each subspace invariant.

I'm confused. Is there any relation between two definitions?

Comment: I don't think so. For example reflexivity of an operator algebra does not depend only on the algebraic and topological structure of the algebra, but how it acts on a vector space, on the other hand reflexivity of a vector space is a property of only the linear and topological structures on the space. Further there are non-reflexive finite-dimensional algebras but no such thing is possible for vector spaces.